# Resize header in Berlin theme to match a header with no circles (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I have get rid of the circles in the header using

```
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
```

Nevertheless, the header is too large because it keeps the size it would have if the circles were still there:

[image]

How can I make the header hegith equal to the text size? (or just specify it manually in some unit)

(This is the code)

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % acentos
\usepackage{listings} % incluir código
\usepackage{caption}  % titulos para los listings
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{comentaryGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}



\usetheme{Berlin} % Antibes (simple)
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}

\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\small}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}
\end{document}**
```

Answer (score 3):

To highlight the issue you need a MWE with sections and subsections, like this:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin} % Antibes (simple)
\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\small}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}

\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\frame{f1}
\frame{f2}
\frame{f3}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\frame{f1}
\frame{f2}
\frame{f3}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I added the class option `compress`, so that the mini frame navigation will only take a single line.

As you already noticed `\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}` does not remove the mini frame navigation but hides it (if you click you'll see they still work).

[image]

Now if you are happy with a single empty line below the section name that's it, we're done. On the other hand, if you don't like the empty line you need some more customization of the `headline` template, like this:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother
```

Add the previous chunk of code after the theme declaration in your preamble and the result will be:

[image]

Now the mini frame navigation is gone for real. If you don't want the section navigation to take all the horizontal space change the `paperwidth` length in `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}` into something more suited to your needs.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @taunch you're welcome : )